# Converting From XDate To Normal Date Format?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

In ZedGraph, I had to convert my date to XDate in order to plot it.
Now, I want to know how to convert from XDate to normal date for some other process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_XDate_DateTime.htm) property

> Gets or sets the date value for this item in .Net DateTime format.

Comment: @Soo - From my reading of the documentation I think it's `DateTime date = XDateVariable.DateTime;`